# The method 'toDouble' was called on null when I call distance

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting my data from model class and when I switch from any other Tab screen to this screen it  takes second or two to get away from this error:-

```
    The method 'toDouble' was called on null.
    Receiver: null
    Tried calling: toDouble().
```

What is the reason for that and how can I get away from this? This is where I am displaying it and commented the line next to where link mentioned in console takes me to when clicked on error:-

```
           Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    child: Card(
                      color: themeProvider.isDarkMode? black :white,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            "Maximum distance",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18,
                                color: mRed,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                          ),
                          trailing: Text(
                            "$distance Km.",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          subtitle: Slider(
                              value: distance.toDouble(),/// Error takes me to this line.
                              inactiveColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                              min: 1.0,
                              max: 500,
                              activeColor: mRed,
                              onChanged: (val) {
                                changeValues
                                    .addAll({'maximum_distance': val.round()});
                                setState(() {
                                  distance = val.round();
                                });
                              }),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

This is another Error in same screen:-

```
     The getter 'start' was called on null.
     Receiver: null
     Tried calling: start


     Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    child: Card(
                      color: themeProvider.isDarkMode? black :white,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            "Age range",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18,
                                color: mRed,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                          ),
                          trailing: Text(
            "${ageRange.start.round()}- // Error take me here ${ageRange.end.round()}",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          subtitle: RangeSlider(
                              inactiveColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                              values: ageRange,
                              min: 18.0,
                              max: 100.0,
                              divisions: 25,
                              activeColor: mRed,
                              labels: RangeLabels('${ageRange.start.round()}',
                                  '${ageRange.end.round()}'),
                              onChanged: (val) {
                                changeValues.addAll({
                                  'age_range': {
                                    'min': '${val.start.truncate()}',
                                    'max': '${val.end.truncate()}'
                                  }
                                });
                                setState(() {
                                  ageRange = val;
                                });
                              }),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `distance` is null, you won't be able to use it properties like `distance.toDouble()`.

One way to avoid the error would be to conditionally assign the value like this,

```
value: distance != null ? distance.toDouble() : 1.0,
```

Now, if `distance` is ever `null` you will be assigning a default `1.0` instead.

```
Text(ageRange != null ? "${ageRange.start.round()} - ${ageRange.end.round()}" : "invalid",
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
),
```

Comment: I changed that as you said now I get this in console:- Failed assertion: line 166 pos 15: 'value >= min && value <= max': is not true.

Comment: Updated my answer, make it `1.0` instead of `0`

Comment: The error is coming since we have provided the `min` as `1.0` but we are giving a value less than `min`

Comment: yes now getting it on another, updated pls check in same screen.

Comment: Text(
      "${ageRange != null ? ageRange.start.round() : "invalid"}",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
    ),

Comment: changed, still getting the same.

Comment: what is the error now ? it shouldve changed

Comment: and where to add ageRange.end with this? as I am trying to but not able follow the syntax.

Comment: hey, I added ageRange.end but  now the error is;- The getter 'end' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: end

Comment: Now it again shifted to this error :-  The getter 'start' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: start

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232774/discussion-between-gagan-singh-and-nisanth-reddy).

Comment: Must be at some other place. you should thoroughly check before commenting. You have multiple places where you are using start and end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232890/discussion-between-gagan-singh-and-nisanth-reddy).